# Rsync not transferring files and no errors

Tags: rsync

So I have files on the server that I'm trying to copy over. I tried doing it to grab by the folder with:

```
rsync -avzh --stats  deploy@website.com:/data/deploy/website/releases/20200309193449/files
```

I even tried just getting a particular file with:

```
rsync -avz --stats  deploy@website.com:/data/deploy/website/releases/20200309193449/files/28/ImportantFile.doc
```

The file is returning:
-rw-rw-r--       48640 2020/04/08 15:13:42 ImportantFile.doc

- Number of files: 1
- Number of files transferred: 0
- Total file size: 48640 bytes
- Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
- Literal data: 0 bytes
- Matched data: 0 bytes
- File list size: 79
- File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
- File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
- Total bytes sent: 16
- Total bytes received: 103

The difference when I try to copy the folder I get the following permissions on the folder:
drwxrwxr-x        4096 2020/04/08 15:13:42 files

Am I missing something? Is there some additional permission I should be putting in the rsync?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here in hopes that someone will get a benefit from my stupidity. Threw a space . at the end of like so:

```
rsync -avzh --stats  deploy@website.com:/data/deploy/website/releases/20200309193449/files .
```

I hope this benefits someone eventually.